# Apply custom discount rule on products before magento default catalog promotion rules

Tags: module, catalog-price-rules

i have a situation where i need to apply a custom price (calculated based on cost price) on products before catalog promotion rules being applied. Currently i have successfully applied product price by overriding

```
getPrice()
```

method from /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php and

```
catalog_product_collection_load_after
```

event. but it blocks catalog rule to be applied. i.e default catalog rules are now disabled. 
In short i want to modify product price before catalog rule being applied. Is there a way i can achieve this? Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price
```

and

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
```

And modify the *getFinalPrice* method to change prices for configurable and simple products.

This will modify the price before any other catalog price rules are applied.

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion, in order to modify product prices i already implemented this method. it works for products without catalog rules.